# I have windows 8 and windows 7 can i install ubuntu to a usb normally

Tags: installation

help me please i so confused with this install!! i have 2 os and want to have 3 but Ubuntu on a USB? 
i have
windows 7
windows 8
and want to install Ubuntu to a USB please help?

Answer (score 0):

Once I managed to install Ubuntu 12.04 in my 16 GB pen drive. Hope you can also install Ubuntu in a pen drive.  I first formatted it into two partitions. *1st* as **EXT4**, gave around 12 GB and *2nd* as **SWAP** gave remaining space. Any how I managed to use Ubuntu from pen drive.

But believe me it didn't worth the installation. It was too slow to response and was taking seconds to open a window. I installed in USB 2.0, so you may give a try on USB 3.0. But I don't think that it will run fast. So I prefer you to just steal some space from your existing Windows partition and install Ubuntu on that. **Gparted** will do this for you.